# .htaccess rewrite subdomain to dynamic url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using htaccess mod-rewrite to rewrite a subdomain url to a dynamic url, for example: **subdomain.example.com/shop** is rewritten to read **example.com/shop/?page=subdomain**

The following code is working fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example\.com/$1/?page=%1 [L,P]
```

But the problem is if we access: **subdomain.example.com** (without the "shop" at end of the url), it display a 404 error page because it reads the url as: **example.com//page=subdomain** with double slashes "//" because the "$1" is empty.

Is there anyway that we can put "$1" in a condition that if it's empty then slash "/" next to it will be removed as well so that the url should be read as **example.com/page=subdomain** with only one slash before the "page" parameter?

Really appreciate if any htaccess experts could help me out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just add a separate rule explicitly for the "nothing there" case:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example\.com/?whatever [L,P]
```

Comment: Thanks @VoteyDisciple, I added it, it works with redirecting (Removed "P" flag), but not working with "P" flag to keep the sub-domain not redirecting, it redirects the sub-domain to main-domain. Do you have any idea for this?